# Java iterate queue when is member of a class

Tags: java, iterator

There's a way to iterate the member variables of an object in Java?
I have this scenario:

```
class ItemToUpdateTipo0 {        
  public String        ticker;

  public ItemToUpdateTipo0() {
  }

  public ItemToUpdateTipo0(String ticker) {
    this.ticker = ticker;
  }
}


public class DataStoreTipo0 {        
  private Queue <ItemToUpdateTipo0> QueueItemToUpdateTipo0 = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<ItemToUpdateTipo0>();
  ...
}
```

There's a way to do something like:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
  DataStoreTipo0 dataStoreTipo0 = new DataStoreTipo0();

  for (ItemToUpdateTipo0 obj : dataStoreTipo0) {
    System.out.println(obj.titolo);        
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sure; reflection. What's your goal?

Comment: See the values of item in QueueItemToUpdateTipo0

Comment: I misunderstood--I thought you meant "iterating the member variables of an object in Java" (like `ticker`), not "iterating the elements of a collection".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have your class implement the Iterable interface for this to work.

e.g.,

```
class DataStoreTipo0 implements Iterable<ItemToUpdateTipo0> {
   private Queue<ItemToUpdateTipo0> queueItemToUpdateTipo0 = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<ItemToUpdateTipo0>();

   @Override
   public Iterator<ItemToUpdateTipo0> iterator() {
      return queueItemToUpdateTipo0.iterator();
   }
}
```

Note that you'll want to edit your code so that it follows Java naming conventions. For instance classes should start with upper-case letters while methods and fields should start with lower-case letters. You'll also not want to try to directly access ItemToUpdateTipo0's fields but rather use public getter and possibly setter methods to do this for you.

Comment: How can i use it in this fashion :public static void main(String[] args){
  DataStoreTipo0 dataStoreTipo0 = new DataStoreTipo0();

  for (ItemToUpdateTipo0 obj : dataStoreTipo0) {
    System.out.println(obj.titolo);        
  }
}

Comment: Have you tried implementing what I just recommended? I've posted a code example.